# How difficult/easy it is to migrate from CME FAST to CME MDP3.0?

Tags: fix, cme

Has anyone gone through this migration? Just wanted to have an idea of the amount of effort required.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to quant finance but to IT

Answer (score 3):

Migration will be hard. You can check [MDP3 Overview - FIX/FAST to MDP 3.0](http://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/EPICSANDBOX/CME+Globex+Legacy+Market+Data+to+MDP+3.0+Market+Data+Conversion#CMEGlobexLegacyMarketDatatoMDP3.0MarketDataConversion-MDP3Overview-FIX/FASTtoMDP3.0) for more details.